# JavaScript images

Tags: javascript

How do I display the same image on the same page multiple times?

```
<head>
<Script language="javascript">
function xdf(){

for (i=0;i<10;i++) {

document.write('<b>hello world</b><br>');
}
}

</script>
</head>
```

this code displays "hello world" 10 times.
i would like the same thing but with certain image instead of "hello word"...

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense at al, could you explain it a bit better? And maybe add some code (if necessary).

Comment: HAL tells me that there are a hundred and thirty seven correct answers to this question based on its current form. Can you narrow it down for us by providing more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
document.write('<b>hello world</b><br>');
```

Into:

```
document.write('<img src="IMAGE FILE NAME HERE.png" alt="TEXT HERE"><br>');
```

Comment: thanks!! it works!!
i tried to do it myself... but obviously i mistyped it.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement) to create an `img` element in JavaScript, and [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/appendchild) to append it to some other node:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'my_image.png');
document.getElemenetById('some-div').appendChild(img);
```

The image will be loaded from the browser's cache if the above is repeated multiple times, appending each new `img` element to multiple nodes.

---

As [@Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47773/matthew-flaschen) suggested in a comment below, you could also use the [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/cloneNode) solution instead. You can create your `img` elment once:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'my_image.png');
```

... and then use `img.cloneNode(false)` as an argument for `appendChild()`:

```
document.getElemenetById('some-div').appendChild(img.cloneNode(false));
document.getElemenetById('some-other-div').appendChild(img.cloneNode(false));
```

Comment: No you can't .  It will be moved.  You would have to clone it.

Comment: Daniel probably means "if you create a new image element, set src and append it to another element". That way there is no need to clone.

Comment: Rather than repeat all three lines, you could alternatively use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/cloneNode).

Comment: @davyM: Yes, that's what is meant now. My previous answer was incorrect. Should be more clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="/path/to/img.png"/> <img src="/path/to/img.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can clone the images:

```
<div><img src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" id="image" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    n = 5;
    img = document.getElementById("image");
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
      img2 = img.cloneNode(false);
      img2.id = img.id + "_clone" + i;
      img.parentNode.appendChild(img2);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it does work!! Thanks!! But how to clone them only along left edge of window?? without right column??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove you can e.g. add `style="float:left;clear:left"` to the `img`, and maybe some padding..

Answer (score 1):

.. or maybe you'd rather want to define the background, using CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
  body { background: url("http://www.google.com/favicon.ico") left repeat-y; }
</style>
```

*(assuming from your previous comment, that you want to have the images in one column on the left edge)*